# Scanning the subnet by ip range

Tags: c++, socket, winapi

By applying the `get_name` and `get_mac` functions to the specified IP address, it is possible to estimate the network availability of a segment:

```
#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <cstdio>

#pragma comment(lib, "iphlpapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

bool get_name(unsigned char* name, char dest[32])
{ 
  struct in_addr destip;
  struct hostent* info;

  destip.s_addr = inet_addr(dest);

  info = gethostbyaddr((char*)&destip, 4, AF_INET);

  if (info != NULL)
{
  strcpy((char*)name, info->h_name);
}
else
{
return false;
}

return true;
}

bool get_mac(unsigned char* mac, char dest[32])
{
  struct in_addr destip;
  ULONG mac_address[2];
  ULONG mac_address_len = 6;

  destip.s_addr = inet_addr(dest);

  SendARP((IPAddr)destip.S_un.S_addr, 0, mac_address, &mac_address_len);

  if (mac_address_len)
  {
   BYTE* mac_address_buffer = (BYTE*)&mac_address;
   for (int i = 0; i < (int)mac_address_len; i++)
    {
    mac[i] = (char)mac_address_buffer[i];
    }
   }
   else
   {
     return false;
   }

    return true;
   }

   int main()
   {
     char address[][32] = { { "192.168.14.101" },{ "192.168.14.102" }, 
                     {"192.168.14.103" },{ "192.168.14.106 "} };
     WSADATA sock;

     if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &sock) != 0)
   {
     printf("Failed to initialise winsock. (%d)\n", WSAGetLastError());
     return 1;
   }

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)sizeof(address) / 32; i++)
    {
     unsigned char mac[6] = { '\0' };
     unsigned char name[100] = { '\0' };

     if (get_mac(mac, address[i]))
    {
      printf("%s : %s : %.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X\n", address[i], 
     (get_name(name, address[i])) ? (char*)name : "-", 
     mac[0],mac[1],mac[2],mac[3], mac[4], mac[5]);
     fflush(stdout);
    }
    }

    printf("\nDone.\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    system("PAUSE");

   return 0;
   }
```

An attempt to implement a program that scans the subnet and displays IP address, host name, and MAC of machines on the network.

Answer (score 3):

I won't cover any bugs in your implementation, I'll only have a look at your coding style. It looks like you were writing plain c but tagged it as c++. I think I didn't even found a single c++-only feature you made usage of.

### Don't use a string as data storage unless it's necessary

And of course, don't use plain c-style strings, because you'll do it wrong.

```
char address[][32] = { { "192.168.14.101" },{ "192.168.14.102" }, 
                 {"192.168.14.103" },{ "192.168.14.106 "} };
```

You reserve 32 chars for your ip-address storage, but that isn't ever necessary. If you really want to store them as a string, do it as `std::string`, or if it's a constant string, as `std::string_view`(C++17). An ip-address has a upper maximum of 4 * 3 signs + 3 dot signs and additionally the zero at the end (that accumulates to a max of 16 signs). So, that means you reserved twice as much memory as you really ever need.

### Use better data type

Why don't you simply store the ip-address as an 32bit uint; or as an `std::array<std::unit8_t, 4>`. You could easily create a typedef for that:
`using ipv4 = std::array<std::unit8_t, 4>` 
With that typedef you'll be able to use that type everywhere you need the ipv4 address. That makes the code more readable and less error prone.

### rethink your return statements

That looks really horrible.

```
bool get_name(unsigned char* name, char dest[32])
{
  // ...
  if (info != NULL)
  {
    // ...
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

You could write that in an easier way:

```
bool get_name(unsigned char* name, char dest[32])
{
  // ...
  if (info != NULL)
  {
    // ...
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

### use std::optional if you expect your function return a invalid return value

In C++17 we got a new helper template class called std::optional. It's very helpfull in returning values with an invalid state. You could adjust your `get_name` function like this:

```
std::optional<std::string> get_name(ipv4 ip)
{
  // ...
  if (info != NULL)
  {
    return info.name; // pseudo-code; don't know the real interface of this info object, but hopefully you get what I try to explain
  }
  return std::nullopt;
}
```

That will make your code more reable and self-descriptive. All of the above is also true for your `get_mac` function.

### c-style cast are bad

You used them alot; don't do that. In c++ there are plenty of cast you should use instead. For example `(int)mac_address_len` should be written as `static_cast<int>(mac_address_len)`